# Cannot break a game after all questions were answered

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a flashcards game to memorize some of the C syntax as suggested on the Book "Learning C the Hard Way" by Zed Shaw (which I just received yesterday with much joy :) !). And I have a problem with the way I am making the Flag to start the game, and set it as False once all questions were answered. Here is my code:

```
def bordered(text):
    """Creates a border around text"""
    lines = text.splitlines()
    width = max(len(s) for s in lines) 
    res = ['┌' + '-' * width + '┐']
    for s in lines:
        res.append('|' + (s + ' ' * width)[:width] + '|')
    res.append('└' + '-' * width + '┘')

    return '\n'.join(res)

Arithmetic_Operators = {
    '+': 'Add',
    '-': 'Substract',
    '*': 'Multiply',
    '/': 'Divide',
    '%': 'Modulus',
    '++': 'Increment',
    '--': 'Decrement',
}


def start():
    score = 0
    Game_Starts = True
    while Game_Starts:
        for k, v in Arithmetic_Operators.items():
            print(bordered(f"What is the meaning of: {k}?"))
            answer = input()
            if  answer == v:
                print("CORRECT!")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("FAILED!")
                correct_answer = bordered(v)
                print(correct_answer)
                score = score - 1
                Game_Starts = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

I am Able to go through all the questions, but the game does not brakes if someone get a wrong answer and the program does not stop once all elements have been depleted in the dictionary. Does anyone could help me to understand this? I thought that in the else block, by setting Game_Starts as false, would accomplish the first. I think that by the second, I have to create maybe an extra dictionary to insert all the correct answers, and delete the questions that have been answered correctly.

Comment: Yes I think that an OPP approach is the better approach for such flashcard game. I just had on top of my head an example of a terminal game, and I started doing my flashcard example without declaring classes and not using OPP at all. Thank you for the help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the While boolean, because the extra variable wasn`t really necessary as any loop can be ended with `break` or just returning from inside it ends it.

The main problem was, that you were breaking the outside loop from the inner loop, which does nothing, because the outside loop never really does a loop

Returning nothing ends the loop

```
def start():
    score = 0
    while True:
        for k, v in Arithmetic_Operators.items():
            print(bordered(f"What is the meaning of: {k}?"))
            answer = input()
            if  answer == v:
                print("CORRECT!")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("FAILED!")
                correct_answer = bordered(v)
                print(correct_answer)
                score = score - 1
                return
```

Alternative `start()` function

```
def start():
    score = 0
    while True:
        for k, v in Arithmetic_Operators.items():
            print(bordered(f"What is the meaning of: {k}?"))
            answer = input()
            if  answer == v:
                print("CORRECT!")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("FAILED!")
                correct_answer = bordered(v)
                print(correct_answer)
                score = score - 1
                break
        break
```

But the cleanest solution would be to get rid of that while loop. (Which while I was writing became a solution by someone else)

Comment: While this fixes the problem, you should at least add some more explanation of what you changed and why you did it

Comment: @Peter: actually, your suggestion to use `return` is nice since you could e.g. return `score`.

Comment: Yes the While loop is innecesary for such implementation. I have to reconsider rewriting the code, because there will be more dictionaries that I want to include on this flashcard game, and OPP seems to be the better approach to write this. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Since you already run the 'game code' in a `for` loop, you don't need the `while` loop at all. Just add `break` (or `return`):

```py
def start():
    score = 0
    for k, v in Arithmetic_Operators.items():
        print(bordered(f"What is the meaning of: {k}?"))
        answer = input()
        if  answer == v:
            print("CORRECT!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("FAILED!")
            correct_answer = bordered(v)
            print(correct_answer)
            score -= 1
            break
```

**suggestions:** You could consider making your input a bit more 'flexible' by using `.upper()` on the strings. You could also consider returning something, e.g. replace `break` with `return score`. And btw. it's 'subtract', not 'substract' ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Definetely, I will implement the .upper() for the string that comes in the answers.